# Can I make my physical computers taskbar allways visible over Thinlic?

Tags: remote-access

I'm new to Thinlinc and my physical machine is windows 7.

I'm using multi monitors fullscreen, but even so, when I get a lync message, my windows taskbar becomes visible and the Lync message stays on top. Is there a way to make the taskbar always visible.

Comment: Is the Windows 7 taskbar currently set to "Auto hide" in its properties? If so, disable that and let us know if it helps.

Comment: No, it is not. The taskbar is locked.